# How to handle controller/views creation in a custom MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, mvp

I'm on an application which should open a GUI specific commands.

I tried to implement a sort of MVC like that (simplified version) :

```
class View1 {
  // Delegate gui framework
  private Gui delegate;

  private Consumer<String> nextButtonCallback;

  private Model model;

  public void open() {
    // open the view here and populate it with model values
    // onButtonClick invoke nextButtonCallback.accept("data");
  }
}
```

```
class EditController1 {
  private Model model;

  public void start() {

  }

  private void openView1() {
    View1 view = new View1(model);
    view.nextButtonCallback= string -> {
       // open a second view
       view.close();
       openView2();
    };
    view.open();
  }

  private void openView1() {
    View2 view = new View2(model);
    view.backButtonCallback = string -> {
       // go back
       view.close();
       openView1();
    };
    view.open();
  }

}
```

```
class Command {

  private ModelService modelService;

  public void onCommand1(String modelId) {
    Model model = modelService.getModel(modelId);
    EditController1 controller = new EditController1 (model);
    controller.start();
  }
}
```

Right now the controller is controlling several views and handling internal navigation (is that a good idea ?)

Now, lets say I have another controller (InfoController) which is opened by another command (infoCommand). I would like to open edition when clicking "edit" button. But since we are in the InfoController I can not open edit views.

Same with "back" button, how to know if InfoController should open info view when EditController views are closed ?

How should I handle navigation between internal and external views with this kind of controllers ?

Or how should I rework to make it better ? :)

Thanks

Comment: The view should create and show the GUI, reading values from the model.  The controller, which can be made up of multiple ActionListeners, updates the model and refreshes the view.  Generally, the model is one or more plain Java classes, the view uses Swing components, except for a drawing JPanel that overrides paintComponent.  The ActionListeners are individual classes that each implement ActionListener.

Comment: Here's one of my [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889181/problems-with-implementing-understanding-mvc-in-java/63893765#63893765) with a simple MVC example.

Comment: I agree with you and I think my impl si following this principle. But my question is more about switching views. When a button is click on the view, the view tells the controller, then the controller has to open another view. Same for back. How to handle that ? (Btw im not using swing).

Comment: I'm not familiar with not Swing, but you have to write methods in the view classes that do view switching.  These methods are called from the controller class.

Comment: I don't get it, My views doesn't have logic and doesn't know other views.
And I want to start from another controller. View create a controller to start it from there.